# How to find the degrees of the polynomials in this particular exponential solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

i have this differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{-2x}y^2-\frac{1}{x}(1+4x+2x^2)y = -\frac{e^{2x}}{x}(1+x+2x^2+x^3)
\end{equation}

and, since it is in the Riccati form, I have the following particular solution for this equation
$$
y_1(x) = q(x)e^{p(x)}
$$
but my problem comes when replacing in the equation. Because, it can be a bit clumsy, but I can't see how to get the degree of the polynomial p (x) and q (x).
I know that I can express the polynomials like
$$
p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^np_i*x^î \\ q(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mq_j*x^j
$$
and their respective derivatives
$$
p'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nip_i*x^{i-1} 
\\
q'(x)=\sum_{j=1}^mjq_j*x^{j-1}
$$
Thus the differential equation
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{-2x}y^2-\frac{1}{x}(1+4x+2x^2)y = -\frac{e^{2x}}{x}(1+x+2x^2+x^3)
\\
\Rightarrow p'(x)q(x)e^{p(x)} + q'(x)e^{p(x)} + e^{-2x}(e^{2p(x)}q(x)^2)-e^{p(x)}q(x)(x^-1+4+2x)
\end{equation}
$$
but then from here I don't know how to find the degrees and polynomials so that $y_1$ is the solution of the ODE. Please, Can you give me a hint about how I can solve the equation?

Comment: Did  you try  $p=2x$  ?

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $e^{p(x)}$ to see that the remaining exponentials become constant, that is, their exponents zero, if $p(x)=2x$. The remaining equation is
$$
q'+q^2-(x^{-1}+2(1+x))q=-(x^{-1}+(1+x)^2)
\\~\\
q'+(q-(1+x))^2-x^{-1}q=-x^{-1}
\\~\\
(q-1-x)'+(q-1-x)^2=x^{-1}(q-1-x)
$$
This shows clearly that $q=1+x$ is a solution. Additionally, the last equation is already in Bernoulli form.

Answer (score 0):

After change $y=ue^{2x}$ you can get Riccati equation with particular solution
$$u=x+1$$
and solution
$$u=\frac{2x}{x^2-C}+x+1.$$
Then general solution is
$$ye^{-2x}=\frac{2x}{x^2-C}+x+1$$